Why does the Rust compiler 'move' memory?
The Rust standard library provides the Pin<Ptr> struct to prevent the value referenced by the Ptr from being moved. This is useful when dealing with data types which refer to themselves. The compiler may otherwise move data in memory when a semantic move is indicated.
The std::pin documentation provides the following example of a semantic move:
// -snip-

// Create a tracker and store the initial address
let mut tracker = AddrTracker::default();
tracker.check_for_move();

// Here we shadow the variable. This carries a semantic move, and may therefore also
// come with a mechanical memory *move*
let mut tracker = tracker;

// -snip-

This then begs the question, why move data to a new location in the first place? If the compiler never moved data, it would seem like we would not need to have this contract.
Edit: As some have pointed out, moving is necessary when passing data from the stack. This does not, however, explain why Pin<Box<T>> is a common construct, as Box points to data on the heap.

If the compiler didn't move data, how would you pass a value to a function? Or return a value from a function? You'd either need to heap-allocate everything a la Python/Java/... or implicitly clone everything like pre-C++11 C++ did. Rust's move semantics allows for very natural way to pass ownership of a value and plays extremely well with RAII.

Pin<Box<T>> is common exactly because the heap is such an easy way to put a value somewhere so it won't ever need to be moved again.

A semantic move may by optimized away such that a physical move is avoided, but such optimizations are not required by the compiler and thus code must be written such that any semantic move could be a physical move.
Some moves cannot be avoided: like assigning a value to or from a different data structure, returning from a function (such that RVO can't be used), requirements from a specific ABI, etc. With many small types it is preferable (performance-wise) to move them anyway rather than access them via indirection.

In order to answer the second part of the question, here is an example where a data on the heap (in Box) is moved out the box.
Starting with Rc as another heap-allocated storage, we see that the attempt to use self as a value in .consume_it() is rejected by the compiler.
This is reasonable because, with Rc, the ownership is shared between multiples owners; moving the value out would be very damaging for the other owners.
On the other hand, the same experiment with Box succeeds because there is only one owner.
Then, moving the value out of the box is considered as dropping the box (probably by some magic on the compiler side, not only the standard library).
Finally, we can prevent that from happening thanks to Pin.
struct Thing {
    txt: String,
}

impl Thing {
    fn use_it(&self) {
        println!("using {:?}", self.txt);
    }
    fn consume_it(self) {
        println!("consuming {:?}", self.txt);
    }
}

impl Drop for Thing {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping {:?}", self.txt);
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        println!("~~~~");
        let t_rc = std::rc::Rc::new(Thing {
            txt: "in rc".to_owned(),
        });
        t_rc.use_it();
        // ERROR: cannot move out of an `Rc`
        // t_rc.consume_it();
    }
    {
        println!("~~~~");
        let t_box = Box::new(Thing {
            txt: "in box".to_owned(),
        });
        t_box.use_it();
        t_box.consume_it();
        // ERROR: borrow of moved value: `*t_box`
        // t_box.use_it();
    }
    {
        println!("~~~~");
        let t_pin_box = std::pin::Pin::new(Box::new(Thing {
            txt: "in pin box".to_owned(),
        }));
        t_pin_box.use_it();
        // ERROR: cannot move out of dereference of `Pin<Box<Thing>>`
        // t_pin_box.consume_it();
    }
}
/*
~~~~
using "in rc"
dropping "in rc"
~~~~
using "in box"
consuming "in box"
dropping "in box"
~~~~
using "in pin box"
dropping "in pin box"
*/

